# The best way to get the array index number for maximum element in the array

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to get the element index that is the highest in the array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(np.where(a==a.max()))
```

Current output:

```
(array([3]),)
```

Expected output:
3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) that returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis:

```
np.argmax(a)

3
```

As you don't supply the axis it will return the index of flattened array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 9]])

np.argmax(a)

7
```

Comment: The index 7 is not suitable I think. We can not use it like a[7]. Why the return is like this?

Comment: @ToughMind As stated, it looks at array in it's flattened version and returns the index max. Also, the return value will always be the 1st occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.argmax()`. It will return the index of the highest value in your array.

For more deatils on the function [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) is a link to the documentation.

`np.argmax()` also works for 2D-arrys:

```py
a = array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])

np.argmax(a)
>>> 5

np.argmax(a, axis=0)
>>> array([1, 1, 1])

np.argmax(a, axis=1)
>>> array([2, 2])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it will return the value of the largest element in the array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

print(np.argmax(a))
```

Comment: This returns the max value, OP wants index.

Comment: sorry. fixed my answer